# Docker - browsing to docker container using its IP

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I started a `Docker` container on my Ubuntu machine and forwarded all the `8080` port to its `80` port using the following command:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 8080:80 -v /var/www/html/work:/var/www my_server --name "server"
```

I used the following command to get my container IP:

```
 sudo docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' server
```

and received:

```
 172.17.0.33
```

I have a php file with `phpinfo()` command in `/var/www/html/work/phpinfo.php`

but when browsing to  `172.17.0.33:8080/phpinfo.php` I receive an error on the browser saying it cannot connect to the server.

My guts tells me I need to expose the container IP to the world somehow, I just don't know how..

In OSX I used the `docker-machine` default ip in order to browse to the container, but in Ubuntu I don't have a docker-machine

**What is the right way to do that?**

Comment: You should not try to connect to `172.17.0.33:80` but `ip-host:8080` since you published this port to your localhost IP stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to contact the server using your host localhost:8080, or your host public IP.

But if you are using the container IP managed by the docker daemon, then you would use the port 80, not the *host* port 8088.

See also "[Network configuration](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/articles/networking/)":

> When Docker starts, it creates a virtual interface named `docker0` on the host machine. It randomly chooses an address and subnet from the private range defined by [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) that are not in use on the host machine, and assigns it to `docker0`.
> Docker made the choice `172.17.42.1/16` when I started it a few minutes ago, for example — a 16-bit netmask providing 65,534 addresses for the host machine and its containers.

> But `docker0` is no ordinary interface. It is a **virtual Ethernet bridge that automatically forwards packets between any other network interfaces that are attached to it.
>
> This lets containers communicate both with the host machine and with each other**.

It is best to use your host which has access only to what is published, instead of the container itself.

Comment: How do you find the ip address of docker0?

Comment: @slashdottir By inspecting the bridge: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45163981/6309 (or setting one yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43629665/6309)

Answer (score 0):

If you run docker in Ubuntu, use the Ubuntu server ip to visit your site.

When you run browser in Ubuntu server, just visit
http://localhost:8080/phpinfo.php