# How to change ip address of docker0 bridge interface on Docker Toolbox

Tags: docker, windows-7

I'm using Docker Toolbox for windows 7, I'm trying to change the ip address of docker0 interface but, having difficulty in finding the exact solution which works for Windows 7. Can anyone please help me in finding the solution.

```
Client:
 Version:      1.12.5
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.4
 Git commit:   7392c3b
 Built:        Fri Dec 16 06:14:34 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.5
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.4
 Git commit:   7392c3b
 Built:        Fri Dec 16 06:14:34 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To change the IP address *Docker* will set on it's `docker0` interface, you have to use the `--bip` option which defines the CIDR (eg. `--bip=10.32.57.1/24`), see ["*Customize the docker0 bridge*" in *Docker* user guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/custom-docker0/).

[*Docker Toolbox*](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox) uses [*Boot2Docker*](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker) (running in a virtual machine) which is based on the [*Tiny Core Linux*](http://tinycorelinux.net) OS.

*Docker* daemon reads `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile` before starting (see ["*Local Customisation*" in *Boot2Docker*'s FAQ](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md#local-customisation-with-persistent-partition)) where a `EXTRA_ARGS` variable is ready to be filled with your custom settings.

Just add your `--bip=...` in `EXTRA_ARGS`'s value part and restart the daemon.

The following command (to type in the *Docker Quickstart Terminal*) will stop the *Docker* daemon, drop any existing rule, delete the interface, add a `--bip` option to `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile` and restart the daemon:

```
docker-machine ssh default "\
    sudo /etc/init.d/docker stop ; \
    sudo iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING ; \
    sudo ip link del docker0 ; \
    sudo sed -i \"/^EXTRA_ARGS='\\$/a --bip=10.32.57.1/24\" /var/lib/boot2docker/profile ; \
    sudo /etc/init.d/docker start \
    "
```

(Content of `/var/lib/boot2docker` is persisted between *Boot2Docker* VM restarts so running this command once should suffice)

You can check with:

```
docker-machine ssh default "ip a show dev docker0"
```

---

If anyone needs the same manipulation on Debian (without *Boot2Docker* thus):

For *Sysvinit*:

```
cat >> /etc/default/docker <<EOT
# Change Docker network bridge:
DOCKER_OPTS="--bip=10.32.57.1/24" # "3257" = "dckr" on a phone keyboard
EOT
```

For *systemd*:

```
cat > /etc/systemd/system/docker.service <<'EOT'
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/docker
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/docker-storage
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/docker-network
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// $OPTIONS \
          $DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS \
          $DOCKER_NETWORK_OPTIONS \
          $BLOCK_REGISTRY \
          $INSECURE_REGISTRY
EOT
mkdir /etc/sysconfig
cat > /etc/sysconfig/docker <<EOT
OPTIONS="--bip=10.32.57.1/24"
EOT
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Then (for both *Sysvinit* and *systemd*):

```
service docker stop
iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
ip link del docker0
service docker start
iptables -t nat -L -n # Check if POSTROUTING table is OK
```