# How to get docker0 ip address platform independently

Tags: docker

I'm building application which needs to have ip address of docker0 without using commands like `ip addr show dev docker0`. Is there any way to get it from docker itself maybe using `docker` command or something else? At least the `docker info` doesn't seem to show it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`docker0` network interface is associated with the default [docker network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network/) `bridge`.
You can access info about it with the [`docker network inspect bridge`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_inspect/).
You can use the `--format` option to get specific value:

```
$ docker network inspect bridge --format='{{json .IPAM.Config}}'
[{"Subnet":"172.17.0.0/16","Gateway":"172.17.0.1"}]
```

Answer (score 22):

Get just the gateway ip with:

```
$ docker network inspect bridge --format='{{(index .IPAM.Config 0).Gateway}}'
172.17.0.1
```